# Hosting Wordpress site along side Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, apache

I have a Rails app and Wordpress instance installed on my server.  Both are working fine.  I have the domain setup like so:

www.domain.com goes to rails app

blog.domain.com goes to the wp instance

However I would like to setup Apache so www.domain.com/blog will go to the wp instance and bypass the rails app.  I have passenger installed.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a route to redirect users to your wordpress site.
**Example**

```
match "/blog" => redirect("http://blog.domain.com"), :as => :blog
```

[reference](http://skyrocketapps.com/blog/web-development/how-to-install-wordpress-alongside-existing-rails-app/)

Comment: I could not get the reference tutorials to work.  It pointed me in the right direction but if you could update your answer with this URL also, which works perfectly, that would be good. http://skyrocketapps.com/blog/web-development/how-to-install-wordpress-alongside-existing-rails-app/